# How to make sure user can't do something on the SAME computer

Tags: java

I have a web application using Java, JSP. I want to make sure a user can only answer the same question on his/her same device ONCE. I try to check IP address on the user's computer. Once the device IP address is used, user can't answer the same question again on the device.

I try to capture the IP address as

```
String ip =  request.getRemoteAddr();
System.out.println("IP Address: "+ip);
```

but the ip printed out as the following. 
IP Address: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`

Please let me how to capture user's device IP address correctly? Or any better way to make sure the same device can't be used twice or more for the same question.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
**I added the following code to *jsp* page trying to capture customer's IP address, but I still keep getting production server IP addresses (I uploaded the app to production site). Could you please let me know why? I should get customers device IP address.**

Thanks in advance!

```
String ip = "";
ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");


if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
   ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");      
}      
if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
   ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");      
}      
if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
   ip = request.getRemoteAddr();      
}    
System.out.println("ip: " +ip);
```

Comment: what would happen if the user was assigned an ip address using DHCP?  Try getting the mac address

Comment: why check for the same device, check for user credentials instead. Probably it's supposed to stop one user from answering multiple times

Comment: You're getting the IPv6 address of your computers loopback interface. The `getRemoteAddr()` method is not very reliable, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423347/problem-with-jsp-getremoteaddress

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat, Thanks for your post. I tried to get customer's mac using Java or Javascript. However, looks like they can't be done according to links below. If you have a solution for this, please let me know, otherwise, I have to get back to using ip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467542/possible-to-get-the-client-mac-address-from-java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

Comment: Hi Stultuske, Thank you very much for your comments. I don't use user credentials for the app,thanks again.

Comment: Hi rdas, Thanks for the information.

Comment: *"Could you please let me know why?"*  - We can't be sure of why.  But one possible reason is that your reverse proxy is not setting any of the headers that you are testing for.  Check the configs.  Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434890/how-to-distinguish-between-known-ip-and-unknown-ip/14435335#14435335, and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434890/how-to-distinguish-between-known-ip-and-unknown-ip/14435335#14435335.  The gist is that it is **impossible** to get the real client IP in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your loopback IPv6 interface because you're accessing this JSP through `localhost`. Try opening `http://<your local IP>:<your AS port>`.

Anyway, to get the remote user IP, first check for `X-Forwarded-For` header. If the user is accessing your web through a proxy server `remoteAddr` will be the proxy address and in this header you may have the remote user address.

```java
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
```

Comment: Hi isalgueiro, Thank you very much for your post. I tried your suggestion, but for some reason, I keep getting production server IP instead of user's device IP address. I have updated details in my original post.

Comment: IMHO you're in the right direction @user11117947, print and check the HTTP headers, maybe you need to use a "less standard" header.